# Should Meta's "hot" tab show hottest content of the last 7 days, like the Newsletter?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, hot-questions, newsletter

Meta's "Hot" tab seems to be based on an algorithm that takes questions into account that are *currently* near the top, and picks out the hottest of them.

This makes sense for a site like Stack Overflow, but for Meta, I find the algorithm used for selection questions for the newsletter much more useful: look at the past 7 days, and show what has been massively upvoted/controversial/active *during that time*. On a "political" site like Meta, a discussion that took place a week ago may still be important to the dedicated user.

Would it make sense to change the "hot" tab's behaviour accordingly on Meta? As kind of an ongoing newsletter digest that is updated all the time, instead of once a week?

As a sub-question, do people use the "hot" tab on Meta, and want to see it stay exactly the way it is?

Comment: Also ones with particularly high voting overall, not just score (e.g. +100, -90).

Comment: I use it so rarely that it took me some clicking around to *find* it.

Comment: I'd probably use it more if it were actually useful (_cough_ i.e. by your suggestion).

Comment: Definitely +1. I never use the Meta hot tab because it's actually less useful for discovering good posts than simply "newest" or "active". I'd think I'd actually use this tab if your suggestion was implemented.